# 'CREATE CREDENTIAL' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: azure

I am still new to azure and need to migrate on premise databases to azure. I have created a blob storage but for sime reasons, I can't create a credential. See query below:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/databases] 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'
, SECRET = '?sv=2018-03-28&ss'
```

Then, am getting an error below:

```
Msg 40514, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'CREATE CREDENTIAL' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

I have searched many online resources but still nothing has helped me

Is there anything am missing out here? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[CREATE CREDENTIAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** is only supported in Azure SQL Managed Instance.  Azure SQL Database Managed Instance is a fully managed SQL Server Database Engine Instance hosted in Azure cloud. A full feature comparison between **Azure SQL** and **Azure SQL Managed Instance** can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features).

Comment: if you need to use the CREATE CREDENTIAL command your options are either SQL Server (starting with 2008) or Azure SQL Database (Managed Instance only).  I'm not a DBA so I don't have any other work-arounds, just letting you know it's not supported in Azure SQL single DB, only Managed instances.